# Setting default of <options> in Laravel with PHP Match

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a filter component that lets a user filter for events on a website. The user needs to see which category is currently selected in the filter. For this there is a URL with parameters.

e.g. `/events?category=1`

The code will match the category to the `<option>` in the `<select>`.

The code:

```
<?php

$selected = 'selected';

if (Request::is('courses')) {
    $category = '0';
    if (request()->get('category')) {
        [$selected, $category] = match (request()->get('category')) {
            '0' => [$selected, '0'],
            '1' => [$selected, '1'],
            '2' => [$selected, '2'],
            '3' => [$selected, '3'],
            '4' => [$selected, '4'],
            '5' => [$selected, '5'],
            '6' => [$selected, '6'],
            '7' => [$selected, '7'],
            '8' => [$selected, '8'],
        };
    }
}

if (Request::is('events')) {
    $category = '1';
    if (request()->get('category')) {
        [$selected, $category] = match (request()->get('category')) {
            '0' => [$selected, '0'],
            '1' => [$selected, '1'],
            '2' => [$selected, '2'],
            '3' => [$selected, '3'],
            '4' => [$selected, '4'],
            '5' => [$selected, '5'],
            '6' => [$selected, '6'],
            '7' => [$selected, '7'],
            '8' => [$selected, '8'],
        };
    }
}

?>

<form class="container">
    <div class="bg-white p-6 rounded-lg">
        <div class="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 gap-6">
            <div>
                <label class="mb-3 inline-block">Category</label>
                <select  aria-label="Category" name="category"  class="w-full bg-gray-200 p-3 rounded-lg">
                    <option value="0" @if ($category === '0') Selected @endif>All</option>
                    <option value="1" @if ($category === '1') Selected @endif>Selected Events 1</option>
                    <option value="2" @if ($category === '2') Selected @endif>Selected Events 2</option>
                    <option value="3" @if ($category === '3') Selected @endif>Selected Events 3</option>
                    <option value="4" @if ($category === '4') Selected @endif>Selected Events 4</option>
                    <option value="5" @if ($category === '5') Selected @endif>Selected Events 5</option>
                    <option value="6" @if ($category === '6') Selected @endif>Selected Events 6</option>
                    <option value="7" @if ($category === '7') Selected @endif>Selected Events 7</option>
                    <option value="8" @if ($category === '8') Selected @endif>Selected Events 8</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="flex items-end">
                <x-button type="submit" class="w-full">Search</x-button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

is there any way to simplify this code? I could only think of this way, but I  am still a beginner with PHP. The Categories are not stored in a DB table, so getting it from the DB is not possible.

Comment: I saw your suggested edit and addressed it [in the addition added in revision 5](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/281915/revisions#rev-body-03255d86-0332-48c6-83b7-16569fb477f0)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Some variable assignments are excessive

Let's look at what `$selected` is set to:

> ```
> $selected = 'selected';
> ```

Then in both of the `match` statements `$selected` is always assigned to `$selected` so the return expressions from the `match` statements can simply return the value for `$category`  - i.e.

> ```
>     [$selected, $category] = match (request()->get('category')) {
>         '0' => [$selected, '0'],
>         '1' => [$selected, '1'],
>         '2' => [$selected, '2'],
>         '3' => [$selected, '3'],
>         '4' => [$selected, '4'],
>         '5' => [$selected, '5'],
>         '6' => [$selected, '6'],
>         '7' => [$selected, '7'],
>         '8' => [$selected, '8'],
>     };
> ```

can be simplified to the following:

```
    $category = match (request()->get('category')) {
        '0' => '0',
        '1' => '1',
        '2' => '2',
        '3' => '3',
        '4' => '4',
        '5' => '5',
        '6' => '6',
        '7' => '7',
        '8' => '8',
    };
```

## Simplify assigning category variable

A simpler way of assigning `$category` would be to check if `request()->get('category')` has an **integer value** between 0 and 8. That could be achieved using [`intval()`](https://www.php.net/intval), [`in_array()`](https://www.php.net/in_array) and [`range()`](https://php.net/range)

```
$requestCategory = request()->get('category');
if (in_array(intval($requestCategory), range(0, 8))) {
    $category = $requestCategory
}
```

## Set category default before checking request value

Removing the `match` statements above could lead to these first two conditions:

```
if (Request::is('courses')) {
    $category = '0';
} else if (Request::is('events')) {
    $category = '1';
}
```

Then the [`isset()`](https://www.php.net/isset) function can be used to check if either of those conditions were `true` and that variable was set:

```
if (isset($category)) {
    $requestCategory = request()->get('category');
    if (in_array(intval($requestCategory), range(0, 8))) {
        $category = $requestCategory;
    }
}
```

### Edit:

I saw in [your suggested edit](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/155802) that you proposed simply checking if there is a value in `request()->get('category')` instead of using `isset($category)` - while it would technically be different functionality than the original code, that could be done instead.

In that case `$requestCategory` could be assigned within the conditional statement, though some argue it is less readable. I will leave it up to you to decide whether to use that or not.

```
if ($requestCategory = request()->get('category')) {
    if (in_array(intval($requestCategory), range(0, 8))) {
        $category = $requestCategory;
    }
}
```

With the assignment moved out of the conditional it could allow for the two conditionals to be combined, allowing for the indentation levels to be decreased:

```
$requestCategory = request()->get('category')
if ($requestCategory && in_array(intval($requestCategory), range(0, 8))) {
    $category = $requestCategory;
}
```

## The template can have a loop

[Blade templates support loops](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#loops). So these repeated lines:

> ```
> <option value="0" @if ($category === '0') Selected @endif>All</option>
> <option value="1" @if ($category === '1') Selected @endif>Selected Events 1</option>
> <option value="2" @if ($category === '2') Selected @endif>Selected Events 2</option>
> <option value="3" @if ($category === '3') Selected @endif>Selected Events 3</option>
> <option value="4" @if ($category === '4') Selected @endif>Selected Events 4</option>
> <option value="5" @if ($category === '5') Selected @endif>Selected Events 5</option>
> <option value="6" @if ($category === '6') Selected @endif>Selected Events 6</option>
> <option value="7" @if ($category === '7') Selected @endif>Selected Events 7</option>
> <option value="8" @if ($category === '8') Selected @endif>Selected Events 8</option>
> ```

Could be simplified to the following. Note it uses the `@selected` directive mentioned in the [Additional Attributes section](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#additional-attributes). This allows for `$selected` to be eliminated.

```
<option value="0" @selected($category === '0')>All</option>
@for ($i = 1; $i < 9; $i++)
    <option value="{{ $i }}" @selected($category == $i)>Selected Events {{ $i }}</option>
@endfor
```

The `range()` function could also be used with a [`@foreach` loop](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#loops):

```
<option value="0" @selected($category === '0')>All</option>
@foreach (range(1, 8) as $i)
    <option value="{{ $i }}" @selected($category == $i)>Selected Events {{ $i }}</option>
@endfor
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this solves most of the issues. The only thing with the loop is that the `<option>` dont have the same names. So it is not always "Selected Events", but "Event Name 1", "Lorem Impsum" etc.

Comment: @Maximilian Instead of a `range` function, you can use an array with all the names. For example: `$categories = ['All', 'Category 1', 'Never gonna give you up', 'Lorem ipsum dolor'];` in the PHP part. Then the loop can be `@foreach ($categories as $i => $name) <option value="{{ $i }}" @selected($category == $i)>{{ $name }}</option> @endfor`.