# Laravel Event Filtering Controller

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-blade

So I am currently writing a function in laravel that handles URL parameter filters.

**How the code works:**
 So we have the following two URL parameters:

`timeframe` and `category`

an URL would look like this:

```
/events?timeframe=3&category=6
```

but it can also look like this

```
/events?timeframe=0&category=0
```

the range for the `timeframe` is from `0` to `6` and for the `category`, `0` to `8`
These parameters are created using this blade template:

**Filter Blade:**

```
@php

if (Request::is('courses')) {
    $timeframe = '0';
    $category = '0';

} else if (Request::is('events')) {
    $timeframe = '0';
    $category = '1';

}


if (request()->has('category')) {
    $requestCategory = request()->get('category');
    if (in_array((int)$requestCategory, range(0, 8))) {
        $category = $requestCategory;
    }
}

if (request()->has('timeframe')) {
    $timeframe = request()->get('timeframe');
}

@endphp

<form class="container @if (Request::is('events')) -mt-24 @endif !pb-0">
    <div class="pt-6 md:pt-0">
        <div class="bg-white shadow p-6 rounded-lg">
            <div class="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 gap-6">
                <div>
                    <label class="mb-3 inline-block">Timeframe:</label>
                    <select aria-label="Timeframe" name="timeframe" class="w-full bg-dark-gray p-3 rounded-lg">
                        <option value="0" @if ($timeframe === '0') selected @endif>Upcoming</option>
                        <option value="1" @if ($timeframe === '1') selected @endif>Today</option>
                        <option value="2" @if ($timeframe === '2') selected @endif>Tomorrow</option>
                        <option value="3" @if ($timeframe === '3') selected @endif>This Week</option>
                        <option value="4" @if ($timeframe === '4') selected @endif>This Month</option>
                        <option value="5" @if ($timeframe === '5') selected @endif>Next Week</option>
                        <option value="6" @if ($timeframe === '6') selected @endif>Next Month</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label class="mb-3 inline-block">Category:</label>
                    <select aria-label="Category" name="category" class="w-full bg-dark-gray p-3 rounded-lg">
                        <option value="0" @if ($category === '0') selected @endif>All Courses and Events</option>
                        <option value="1" @if ($category === '1') selected @endif>Events</option>
                        <option value="2" @if ($category === '2') selected @endif>Example 1</option>
                        <option value="3" @if ($category === '3') selected @endif>Example 2</option>
                        <option value="4" @if ($category === '4') selected @endif>Example 2</option>
                        <option value="5" @if ($category === '5') selected @endif>Example 3</option>
                        <option value="6" @if ($category === '6') selected @endif>Example 4</option>
                        <option value="7" @if ($category === '7') selected @endif>Example 5</option>
                        <option value="8" @if ($category === '8') selected @endif>Example 6</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mt-3 flex items-end">
                <x-button type="submit" class="w-full">Search</x-button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Controller:**
I first set the `$category` with the `$request->query('category')`. This is only done if the URL has parameters, and is not `0` Because an URL can also just be like `/events` and the `0` for the `category` should show all events from `1` to `8`.

After this I am setting the variables for the specific routes. `/courses` and `/events`.

Now I am filtering the `timeframe` with the carbon dates. The values are the following:

0 = Upcoming 
1 = Today
2 = Tomorrow
3 = This Week
4 = This Month
5 = Next Week
6 = Next Month
default = Upcoming (all events after `now()`)

I am not sure if this is the correct way to do this, because I am just adding 999 years to get all events from the DB for the `upcoming`.

Now I am returning the view. This is done dynamically, based on the `all` variable from the route. I am also checking if the `$category` is set. If it is true I am checking the `category` in the query. If not it will check all events on the database.

```
   public function coursesList(Request $request)
    {

    // check if category is zero
    if ($categoryParameter === '0') {
        $category = false;
    }

    if ($categoryParameter !== '0' && $categoryParameter >= '9') {
        $category = false;
    }

    // check against known list of categories
    if ($categoryParameter !== '0' && $categoryParameter <= '8') {
        $category = $request->query('category');
    }
    

    // setting for /kursangebote page
    if ($all === 1) {
        $view = 'pages.all-events';
        if (!$request->filled('category')) {
            $category = false;
        }
    }

    // setting for /events page
    if ($all === 0) {
        $view = 'pages.course.event-list';
        if (!$request->filled('category')) {
            $category = '1';
        }
    }

        if ($request->has('timeframe')) {
            $now = CarbonImmutable::now();
            [$startDate, $endDate] = match ($request->get('timeframe')) {
                '1' => [$now , Carbon::today()->endOfDay()],
                '2' => [Carbon::tomorrow()->startOfDay(), Carbon::tomorrow()->endOfDay()],
                '3' => [$now, Carbon::now()->endOfWeek()->endOfDay()],
                '4' => [$now, Carbon::now()->endOfMonth()->endOfDay()],
                '5' => [$now->next(Carbon::MONDAY)->startOfDay(), Carbon::now()->next(Carbon::MONDAY)->endOfWeek()->endOfDay()],
                '6' => [$now->startOfMonth()->addMonth()->startOfMonth(), Carbon::now()->startOfMonth()->addMonth()->endOfMonth()->endOfDay()],
                default => [$now, Carbon::now()->startOfMonth()->addYears('999')->endOfMonth()->endOfDay()],
            };
        } else {
            // default if no timeframe is set as URL parameter
            $startDate = Carbon::now();
            $endDate = Carbon::now()->startOfMonth()->addYears('999')->endOfMonth()->endOfDay();
        }

        return view($view, [
            'events' => Events::withCount('tickets')
                ->withMin('tickets', 'price')
                ->orderBy('start')
                ->when($category, function ($query, $category) {
                    $query->where('category', $category);
                })
                ->whereBetween('start', [$startDate, $endDate])
                // add pagination
                ->paginate(16)

        ]);
    }
```

**Router:**

```
// events list view
Route::get('/events', [
    'all' => 0,
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\EventsController@coursesList'
])->name('event-list');

Route::get('/courses', [
    'all' => 1,
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\EventsController@coursesList'
])->name('all-events');
```

**My question:**
Are there better ways to handle the first four `if` statements in the controller? And how would be the correct way to filter the db query for the upcoming setting? Maybe there are also other ways to improve this code, I would be very happy for some suggestions! :)

Answer (score 2):

I think overall your code is pretty good. It was a little hard to tell what your view would call if the form was submitted (maybe you aren't using that part??)

Anyway, I took a stab.

I think, based on my limited knowledge of your app, you can boil your controller down to something like this

```
public function events(Request $request)
{
    $category = $request->get('category') ?? 1;
    $timeframe = $request->get('timeframe') ?? false;
    return $this->coursesList($category, $timeframe, 'pages.all-events');
}

public function courses(Request $request)
{
    $category = $request->get('category') ?? false;
    $timeframe = $request->get('timeframe') ?? false;
    return $this->coursesList($category, $timeframe, 'pages.course.event-list');
}

public function coursesList($category, $timeframe, $view)
{
    // if the category is set as URL parameter, check if it is range 1-8
    if($category !== false){
        // cast category to int, prevents bogus data from users
        $category = (int)$category;
        if($category <= 0 || $category >= 9){
            $category = false;
        }
    }

    if ($timeframe) {
        // cast timeframe to int, prevents bogus data from users
        $timeframe = (int)$timeframe;
        $now = CarbonImmutable::now();
        [$startDate, $endDate] = match ($timeframe) {
            1 => [$now, Carbon::today()->endOfDay()],
            2 => [Carbon::tomorrow()->startOfDay(), Carbon::tomorrow()->endOfDay()],
            3 => [$now, Carbon::now()->endOfWeek()->endOfDay()],
            4 => [$now, Carbon::now()->endOfMonth()->endOfDay()],
            5 => [$now->next(Carbon::MONDAY)->startOfDay(), Carbon::now()->next(Carbon::MONDAY)->endOfWeek()->endOfDay()],
            6 => [$now->startOfMonth()->addMonth()->startOfMonth(), Carbon::now()->startOfMonth()->addMonth()->endOfMonth()->endOfDay()],
            default => [$now, Carbon::now()->startOfMonth()->addYears('999')->endOfMonth()->endOfDay()],
        };
    } else {
        // default if no timeframe is set as URL parameter
        $startDate = Carbon::now();
        $endDate = Carbon::now()->startOfMonth()->addYears('999')->endOfMonth()->endOfDay();
    }

    return view($view, [
        'events' => Events::withCount('tickets')
            ->withMin('tickets', 'price')
            ->orderBy('start')
            ->when($category, function ($query, $category) {
                $query->where('category', $category);
            })
            ->whereBetween('start', [$startDate, $endDate])
            // add pagination
            ->paginate(16)

    ]);
}
```

Which would allow you to remove the "all" from your routes since they are going to separate controller methods.

```
Route::get('/courses', [\App\Http\Controllers\EventsController::class, 'courses']);
Route::get('/events', [\App\Http\Controllers\EventsController::class, 'events']);
```

Your query looks good to me.

Again I'm not super familiar with the architecture of your app.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the advice in the answer by Rager. Specifying certain controller methods per route, as was done in [your first question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/283008/120114) is a common way to have more succinct methods.

## Indentation levels are inconsistent

Perhaps there may have been issues with pasting code into the editor here but it appears that some of the indentation levels are inconsistent- For example in the controller method `coursesList` these lines appear in the middle of the method:

> ```
> // setting for /events page
>     if ($all === 0) {
>         $view = 'pages.course.event-list';
>         if (!$request->filled('category')) {
>             $category = '1';
>         }
>     }
>
>         if ($request->has('timeframe')) {
> ```

For readability it is best to keep indentation levels consistent.

## Blade template loop can be used to simplify repeated lines

As I explained at the end of [this review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/281915/120114) [blade templates support loops](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#loops) and those can simplify redundant lines of options. The template in the code above has repetitive lines for the `<option>` elements in the select list for the category select list:

> ```
> <option value="2" @if ($category === '2') selected @endif>Example 1</option>
> <option value="3" @if ($category === '3') selected @endif>Example 2</option>
> <option value="4" @if ($category === '4') selected @endif>Example 2</option>
> <option value="5" @if ($category === '5') selected @endif>Example 3</option>
> <option value="6" @if ($category === '6') selected @endif>Example 4</option>
> <option value="7" @if ($category === '7') selected @endif>Example 5</option>
> <option value="8" @if ($category === '8') selected @endif>Example 6</option>
> ```

This is very repetitive and does not comply with the  [Don't repeat yourself (DRY) principle](http://deviq.com/don-t-repeat-yourself/). It also has two options with “Example 2”. Presuming there should only be one option with “Example 2”, it could be simplified using a loop with the `@selected` directive mentioned in the [Additional Attributes section](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#additional-attributes)

```
<option value="0" @if ($category === '0') selected @endif>All Courses and Events</option>
<option value="1" @if ($category === '1') selected @endif>Events</option>
@for ($i = 2; $i < 9; $i++)
    <option value="{{ $i }}" @selected($category == $i)>Example {{ $i - 1 }}</option>
@endfor
```

The `range()` function could also be used with a [`@foreach` loop](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#loops):

```
<option value="0" @if ($category === '0') selected @endif>All Courses and Events</option>
<option value="1" @if ($category === '1') selected @endif>Events</option>
@foreach (range(2, 8) as $i)
    <option value="{{ $i }}" @selected($category == $i)>Example {{ $i - 1 }}</option>
@endfor
```