# Production-Readiness Advice for Laravel/ PayPal Integration

Tags: php, security, laravel, e-commerce, web-services

I am currently working on integrating PayPal with my Laravel application, and it's my first time incorporating PayPal for production use. I have written the following code and would greatly appreciate your expertise in reviewing it for potential issues and ensuring its readiness for production.

**Objective**

I intend to use PayPal to purchase lead packages for my site.

**Code**

Below is a snippet of the relevant code

```
<?php

namespace App\Paypal;

use App\Models\Comptor;
use App\Models\Event;
use App\Models\Package;
use App\Models\Purchase;
use App\Models\User;
use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Core\PayPalHttpClient;
use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Core\ProductionEnvironment;
use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Core\SandboxEnvironment;
use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Orders\OrdersGetRequest;
use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Payments\AuthorizationsCaptureRequest;
use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Payments\AuthorizationsGetRequest;
use \Illuminate\Http\Request;
use PayPalHttp\HttpException;
use Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException;

class PaypalPayment
{
    private $clientSecret;
    private $clientId;
    private $sandbox;


    /**
     * @param string $clientId
     * @param string $clientSecret
     * @param bool $sandbox
     */

    public function __construct(string $clientId, string $clientSecret, bool $sandbox){
        $this->clientId = $clientId;
        $this->clientSecret = $clientSecret;
        $this->sandbox = $sandbox;
    }
    /**
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function handle(Request $request){
        // Retrieve the authorization_id sent from the frontend
        $authorizationID = $request->input('authorization_id');
        // Create a PayPal client to capture funds
        $environment = $this->sandbox
            ? new SandboxEnvironment($this->clientId, $this->clientSecret)
            : new ProductionEnvironment($this->clientId, $this->clientSecret);

        $client = new PayPalHttpClient($environment);
        try {
            // Check authorization status
            $requestAuthorization = new AuthorizationsGetRequest($authorizationID);
            $responseAuthorization = $client->execute($requestAuthorization);
            if ($responseAuthorization->result->status !== 'CREATED') {
                throw new \Exception('Error: authorization not completed');
            }

            // Recover order ID from authorization
            $orderId = $responseAuthorization->result->supplementary_data->related_ids->order_id;

            // Check order status
            $requestOrder = new OrdersGetRequest($orderId);
            $responseOrder = $client->execute($requestOrder);

            if ($responseOrder->result->status !== "COMPLETED") {
                throw new \Exception('Error: order not completed');
            }

            $package = Package::find($request->input('package_id'));
            $user = User::find(session()->get("user"));

            // Check whether the amount captured corresponds to the expected amount
            $amountCaptured = intval($responseAuthorization->result->amount->value);

            if ($package->price !== $amountCaptured) {
                throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json(['success' => false, 'message' => 'Erreur lors de la capture des fonds.'], 500));
            }

            // Save the order ID in your database here

            $comptor = Comptor::where('user_id', '=', $user->id)->first();

            if($comptor){
                $purchase = Purchase::create([
                    "user_id" => $user->id,
                    "package_id" => $package->id
                ]);

                $comptor->increment("leads", $package->nb_lead);

                if($purchase){
                    return response()->json(['status' => true, 'message' => 'Package successfully purchased and the number of your leads to increase by: ' . $package->nb_lead . 'leads']);
                }
            }

            $purchase = Purchase::create([
                "user_id" => $user->id,
                "package_id" => $package->id
            ]);

            $comptor = Comptor::create([
                "user_id" => $user->id,
                "leads" => $package->nb_lead
            ]);

            if($purchase && $comptor){
                return response()->json(['status' => true, 'message' => 'Package successfully purchased and you are entitled to '. $package->nb_lead . 'leads']);
            }

        } catch (\PayPalHttp\HttpException $ex) {
            // Fund capture failed
            // You can manage errors here
            return response()->json(['status' => false, 'message' => 'Error during fund capture.']);
        }
    }
}
```

**Specific Concerns**: I want to know if this code will transfer to my Paypal account.

**Additional Context**: I use Laravel 8.83 and Paypal checkout SDK with JavaScript, but with server-side authorization (my Laravel server).

**What I'm Looking For**

- General code review for potential bugs or security vulnerabilities.
- Feedback on best practices for integrating PayPal into a Laravel
  application.
- Advice on ensuring the code is production-ready.

**Note**:

I have already referred to the official PayPal documentation and followed the guidelines, but as a first-time user, I want to ensure I haven't missed anything crucial.

Can you please provide valuable insights? I'm eager to learn from the community's expertise and improve my implementation.

Comment: @Billal Begueradj, I didn't understand your message, tell me, with this code, is the deposit in my payPal account?

Answer (score 1):

## Foreward

I have not used the Paypal API though I have used PHP and Laravel for many years. I don't spot any bugs or security vulnerabilities, though that does not mean there is no possibility of them being present. The advice below should help simplify the code.

## Code Review

### Variable `$purchase` is created inside conditional block as well as outside block

There is a check to see if `$comptor` is not `false`-y and if so `$purchase` is created. Outside of that block is an identical creation of `$purchase`.

[image: screenshot of duplicate code]

The creation of that variable could happen before the conditional line `if($comptor){` - i.e. unconditionally. As was mentioned in [this review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/283224/120114) this would make it comply with the [Don't repeat yourself (DRY) principle](http://deviq.com/don-t-repeat-yourself/).

### Spacing is inconsistent

There are some `if` statements followed by a space - e.g.

> ```
>         if ($responseOrder->result->status !== "COMPLETED") {
> ```

and

> ```
>         if ($package->price !== $amountCaptured) {
> ```

Yet others are not followed by a space - e.g.

> ```
>         if($comptor){
> ```

For the sake of readability it would be wise to keep spacing consistent. Many PHP developers follow a style guide - e.g. [PSR-12: Extended Coding Style](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/).

### Constructor and properties can be simplified

As of the time of writing [PHP 8.1 and 8.2 are the currently supported versions with Active support](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php). With PHP 8 [Contructor Promotion](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php#language.oop5.decon.constructor.promotion) can be used to greatly simplify the code in the constructor.

The following lines:

> ```
> private $clientSecret;
> private $clientId;
> private $sandbox;
>
> /**
>  * @param string $clientId
>  * @param string $clientSecret
>  * @param bool $sandbox
>  */
>
> public function __construct(string $clientId, string $clientSecret, bool $sandbox){
>     $this->clientId = $clientId;
>     $this->clientSecret = $clientSecret;
>     $this->sandbox = $sandbox;
> }
> ```

Can be simplified to this:

```
/**
 * @param string $clientId
 * @param string $clientSecret
 * @param bool $sandbox
 */
public function __construct(
    private string $clientId, 
    private string $clientSecret, 
    private bool $sandbox
){
}
```

### Eloquent shortcut method can be used for simplification

Instead of calling the Eloquent `where()` method and then calling `first()`:

> ```
>             $comptor = Comptor::where('user_id', '=', $user->id)->first();
> ```

One could simply call the `firstWhere()` method:

```
$comptor = Comptor::firstWhere('user_id', '=', $user->id);
```

Additionally the `'='` can typically be omitted:

```
$comptor = Comptor::firstWhere('user_id', $user->id);
```

See the Laravel **Database: Query Builder** section [Where Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#where-clauses):

> For convenience, if you want to verify that a column is `=` to a given value, you may pass the value as the second argument to the `where` method.